# How do I show that $e^xe^y = e^{x+y}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assuming 
$$e^{x}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!},$$

show that $e^{x}e^{y}$ = $e^{x+y}$.

I have expanded both but am not sure if I need to multiply the two summations and show that product or if there is a simpler way of showing this.

Comment: Can you show what you mean by expanded sums? Also use $ signs around your equations to make the math formatting work. :)

Comment: $e^x$ = 1 + $x^2/2$ + $x^3/3!$ + .........       and  $e^y$ = 1 + $y^2/2$ + $y^3/3!$ + ....

Comment: Thanks the question is much more clear now!

Comment: There is a shorter notation if you are familiarized with ODEs: for every $y\in \mathbb{R}$ both are solutions to the IVP $\frac{d\phi}{dx}=\phi$, $\phi(0)=e^y$, which has locally unique solution. This is essentially the same.

Comment: Use the Cauchy product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product (this exact example is given on that page)

Comment: @User8128 is the Cauchy Product the same as a multiplication? It's defined as a convolution. That may not mean the same as multiplying two sums of real numbers, correct?

Comment: You can prove that $e^x e^y = e^{x+y}$ by multiplying the power series for $e^x$ and $e^y$ using the Cauchy product.

Comment: Thank you! Cauchy Product was exactly what I needed to see to get it.

Comment: You can also refer to "Real and Complex Analysis" by Walter Rudin. He proves this result in the prologue itself using the properties of absolutely convergent series.

Comment: @User8128 I got the answer to my question. The fact that the Cauchy Product (which is actually a convolution) is equal to the product is Merten's theorem which holds under some particular convergence rules.